# Large local key-value storage, what should i use?

Tags: java, database, data-structures, key-value

I have a bunch of key-value pairs, the key being an id and the value an array or list. I want to be able to store these values on the disk, so I can access them later, but probably also have the database in memory, if that increase performance. The database will contain around 5000 pairs, around 4-5 megabytes worth of data. What's the best system for me to use in this situation? It has to be something I can ship with java code, and I have to be able to effectively search the the database for a specific key and do something with the value.

I have searched around for a similar question, but found nothing that asked the same question as me, which I find strange because surely I'm not the first one to wonder about this. So if this is a duplicate, please link me the other question.

I honestly have no idea where to start, but if someone could just recommend me a system that fits my needs, I'll probably figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: 4-5 MB is not too much for me. `HashMap` with 5000 entries should work

Comment: So, can i just store this, load it into memory and effectively search it? I had thought I needed some kind of database, like SQLite, Java DB or  whatever it most appropriate for my situation.

Comment: Of course, if you have enough memory, 5MB is not a problem and you can retrieve your pair by key. `Map` search algorithm  by hash is really fast. For me, is no problem, but that is my opinion ;)

Comment: @TobLoef If you only need a key-value store, a `Map` is more than suitable. Small amounts in the thousands or tens of thousands don't require a database, unless you really want one, or you need to query the data in more ways than just a simple retrieval by key.

Comment: Great guys, thanks a bunch. I will proceed with a map. If someone writes it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Also, consider persisting data in a no-sql storage. That is, if you need the data to be persisted. Properly indexed noSQL storages such as Mongo or whatever will run extremely fast (not as fast as memory "queries", but close enough).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Xodus KV](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus). That is a key-value store used in production by JetBrains in the [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) product. It provides snapshot isolation with readers not competing with writers. JetBrains actively supports it.

Xodus also has an [entity store](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores) solution which, along with [ORM](https://jetbrains.github.io/xodus-dnq/) implemented in Kotlin, can be used as a primary database in your project. It also has support for [blobs](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#blobs).